# Loop throught checkboxes and delete hidden copies javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so, im trying to create a loop and a loop inside that loop. The point is to create a remove function. I have a list of users and copies of those same users hidden. Purpose of copies is show them on clicking 'online' link or 'offline' link or 'all'. When i want to remove a user i made a checkbox for each user, by clicking the checkbox, it pushes that element into an array. then when i click minus it removes that user and loops thru the hidden copies and removes the ones match the id. It works fine for one user, or if i check/select users from the bottom of the list going up, then it loops thru the array perfectly fine and removes all copies from DOM. But if i do it the normal way by selecting per say the first user on the list then second then third etc, it will only loop thru the first user element. but in console, it shows that the array has the users i pushed into, and it will actually loop thru that first element the amount of times as how many users i pushed into it.
Someone pointed out to not using duplicate ids and i knew that, but i didnt know how else to get this done, i tried using title, name, but cant use classes cuz i have multiple classes on the elements. Im mindfckd as to why it works if i select elements backwards. this is a isolated example from my project, so it only has one class and i dont have hidden copies. this is just so someone helping can better see what im tryin to do. the visible copies need to dissapear by checking only one copy but it has the same bug, html doesnt seen to show parent div..

http://codepen.io/Pagnito/pen/vmLOvj?editors=1010

```js
function minus() {
  $('.fa-minus').click(function() {

    if ($('.chBox').is(':checked')) {

      var div = $(':checked').closest('div');
      var dib = div.next();
      $(checkedArr).each(function(i, iteM) {
        console.log(checkedArr)
        var ch = iteM;
        var chkd = $(ch).attr('id')
        console.log(chkd)
        console.log('hi' + i)
        $('.g').each(function(index, item) {
          var ite = $(item).attr('id')

          if (ite == chkd) {

            $(item).remove();
            var dib = div.next('#acc');
            $(dib).remove();
          }
        })
      })
      var dib = div.next('#acc');
      $(dib).remove();
      $(':checked').closest('a').remove();
      checkedArr = [];
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group hidden-xs-down streams">
  <div class="g" class="free"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">Free</div>
  <div class="g" id="ninja"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">ninja</div>
  <div class="g" id="big"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">big</div>
  <div class="g" id="free"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">Free</div>
  <div class="g" id="ninja"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">ninja</div>
  <div class="g" id="big"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">big</div>
  <div class="g" id="free"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">Free</div>
  <div class="g" id="ninja"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">ninja</div>
  <div class="g" id="big"><input class="chBox" type="checkbox" name="user">big</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `en minus()`?

Comment: oh yea thats a typo, i tried to use that for stackoverflow so it included click(function) in the code text too. cuz it didnt include it for some reason

Comment: if u click the link, its much easier to see what im talking about tho

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: i did, you cant see it?

Comment: You wrote **if u click the link, its much easier to see what im talking about tho** We shouldn't have to click a link to see what you're talking about, anything important should be here.

Comment: I don't see `id="acc"` anywhere in the codepen. What is `div.next("#acc")` supposed to select?

Comment: Are you sure `checkedArr` contains what you want? Every time you click on `.firstCol`, it adds another jQuery collection containing all the checked DIVs to `checkedArr`, not just the one that you clicked on. So `checkedArr` will probably contain lots of duplicates.

Comment: And the elements of `checkedArr` will not be single elements. Each element of the array will be a collection of all the DIVs containing checked boxes at the time that the user clicked. Then `var chkd = $(ch).attr('id')` will just get the ID of the first one in the collection.

Comment: This code all seems very relevant to the problem you're having, but you haven't posted it here. See what I mean?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need `checkedArr` at all. When the user clicks on the minus, just find all the checked boxes, and delete all the DIVs that are related to them.

Comment: yup, i just figured out the same thing, each array index has all the pushed elements, i changed to it to push event.target.closest and its working, now i just gotta figure out how to remove the element if its unchecked

Comment: this is a copy of the actual code, in the actual code the loop goes thru hidden copies. i didnt want to post the whole app im working on, its kind of alot, not like a whole lot but i didnt feel there was a need